# Weird http requests coming into AWS Elastic Beanstalk Server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I noticed on the logs on CloudWatch that we are receiving some random weird http requests in our AWS Elastic Beanstalk server.

These requests I know is coming from AWS Beanstalk itself, the load balancer probably?
The reason I know is I also received legit health check request which I configured.

Example.

I configured that our health check route is on `/healthz`
And I received get requests coming from IP 172.31.x.x towards that route, so I know that is the load balancer checking for the health of the app in our beanstalk server.

However,

We see the same IP 172.31.x.x is sending additional weird requests into the app.

Examples:

- GET  | /exactarget/
- GET  | /.env
- HEAD | /Core/Skin/Login.aspx
- GET  | //phpMyAdmin/scripts/setup.php # yes double slash at the start
- GET  | /phpinfo
- GET  | /info.php
- GET  | /_profiler/phpinfo

There a lot more burried down our logs.

I've researched and can't find clear explanation about these and how to prevent these unnecessary requests to our app in the beanstalk. It pollutes the logs and cause unnecessary stress on our app.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `172.31.x.x` is a non-routable address, meaning that it isn't coming directly from the internet.  These are basic hacking attempts and they should be coming from whatever is in front of your beanstalk servers like a load balancer or something like that.  It's certainly possible that your `/healthz` calls are also coming in through the load balancer too.

Comment: I am facing a similar issue. Did anyone find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You need to log traffic at the load balancer to S3 for analysis. This is not trivial as there is JSON involved that varies according the age of your region, but is doable.

Load balancers are under the EC2 menu. Anything more I write here will date.

You will see one or two IP addresses for HTTP traffic on the instances, TLS is offloaded at the load balancer too.

Two IP addresses just means you have load balancers in two zones.

You can then (with extreme care) firewall them out of the VPC by ACL entry for a day if it is the one persistent IP.

What you cannot do without WAF is route these usual suspects somewhere else before they hit your app. But your Webserver may be able to suppress or drop  them.  Yet more effort.